# How to convert a SQL date to a DateTime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, date, datetime

I have a column with the `date` type in my SQL database. How can I convert it to C# `DateTime` and then back again to a SQL `date`?

Comment: how are you retrieving the records?

Comment: I want to use something like 'Select * from News where add_date < @selected_date'
And I use SqlDataReader

Answer (score 14):

A sql `DATE` can be directly cast to a .net `DateTime` and vice-versa.

to get it, use the [SqlDataReader.GetDatetime Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdatetime.aspx)

```
DateTime myDate = myDataReader.GetDateTime(myColumnIndex);
```

to set it, simply assign it to the value of the [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) and use the `.Date` property of the DateTime

Comment: Thx. I am confused when msdn says "No conversions are performed; therefore, the data retrieved must already be a DateTime object."

Comment: What would be the best way of going about it if the index isn't known and only the column name is?

Answer (score 8):

c#
To get date from reader

```
DateTime date1;
DateTime.TryParse(reader["datecolumn"], out date1);
```

To insert date

```
string date1="2013-12-12"; 
DateTime date2;
DateTime.TryParse(reader["datecolumn"],out date2);

SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("Insert into table (dateColumn) Values(@date2)",connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date2",date2.Date);
```

TryParse returns true on successful casting false otherwise.

VB

To get date from reader

```
Dim date1 as Date=CType(reader("dateColumn"),Date)
```

To insert date

```
 Dim date1 as String="2013-12-12" 'you can get this date from an html input of type date

 Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Insert into table (dateColumn) Values(@date1)",connection)
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1",CType(date1, Date))
```

NOTE:Code is written in VB. You can easily write the c# equivalent of the above code. The function name remains the same in both VB and c#. Also CType is not available in c#(though its the same as explicitly casting a variable eg. `date1=(DateTime)reader("dateColumn");` I would recommend using `TryParse` which doesn't throw any exception on unsuccesful parses/casting.

Syntax

```
Date.TryParse(reader("dateColumn"), date1)
```

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance Did you even read my answer before voting it down?? Do you even know what VB and C# are and how there is practically a very little difference between them??

Comment: @thunderbird Macintosh apples aren't Granny Smith apples, although they are both apples. If you wanted one and were given another you might be annoyed or at least confused / surprised.

Comment: @Yuck i have given instructions on how to convert it to c#. Besides VB and C# is like coding in java and C++. If you know one, you got the other one. I will anyway translate it to c#.

Comment: -1: you should provide c# examples. If you feel vb.net and c# are so similar, why can't you be bothered to provide a c# example?

Comment: @thunderbird **I do, I just think that if the OP asks for C#, he should get C#**

Comment: And also, Java and C++ is a **TERRIBLE, TERRIBLE** comparison. At least C++ is useful.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance again i am talking about the basic syntax only. I agree i overlooked the c# part because i looked for it in the tag section when it normally should be.

Comment: An error in your C# code: C# comments start with `//`, not with `'`.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance give me a break i copy pasted my vb code and made changes to it.

Answer (score 3):

```
 string mydate= Convert.ToDateTime(reader["dateColumn"]).ToShortDateString().ToString());
```

These code is working for me.Try these one