# Pulling dateTime from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, datetime

I'm attempting to compare an `endDate` column in a SQL Server database to a stored variable called `highDate` in c#.

```
DateTime highDate = new DateTime(2999, 1, 1);

SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("My connection string");
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("My query including endDate_TS", myConnection);

myCommand.Connection.Open();

SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

while (myReader.Read())
{
      DateTime endDate = new DateTime(myReader["endDate_TS"]); //something is wrong here
}

if (endDate > highDate)
{
   //do something
}
```

How do I correctly format the `endDate` variable I created to accept the `endDate_TS` from the SQL Server database? (the `endDate_TS` is a SQL Server `DATETIME` datatype)

Comment: look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16634940/how-to-convert-a-sql-date-to-a-datetime

Comment: What do you mean by "something is wrong here", do you get exception, is your column `null`, try comparing it against `DBNull.Value` before converting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateTime` has several [constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) but none which takes an object. But `myReader["endDate_TS"]` returns an object. If it's actually the number of ticks (what it seems to be if `_TS` means TimeSpan) you can use the [constructor that takes a `long`:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
int indexOfEndDateTsColumn = myReader.GetOrdinal("endDate_TS");
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(myReader.GetInt64(indexOfEndDateTsColumn));
```

However, the last sentence in parentheses suggests that it's actually a `datetime` in the database, then you can use `DataReader.GetDateTime` directly:

```
DateTime endDate = myReader.GetDateTime(indexOfEndDateTsColumn);
```