# Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, casting

I have an application that get a datetime value from the database but it give me this error

> Specified cast is not valid

here is the code

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Golden_RoseConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

con.Open();
String sel3 = "select Booking_Date from booking where Booking_ID='" + Booking_Id + "'";
SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand(sel2, con);
SqlDataReader n3 = cmd3.ExecuteReader();
n3.Read();
DateTime Booking_Date = (DateTime)n3.GetSqlDateTime(0);
con.Close();
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Could your result be returning a null value ?

Comment: It would be better to change your `Booking_Date` column type to `datetime` or better `datetime2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

```
var Date = Convert.ToDateTime(n3["YOUR_DATE_COLUMN"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

an sql date is not a .Net `DateTime` object.

`GetSqlDateTime` does not do a convertion - [see MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqldatarecord.getsqldatetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

It must be converted - [see the SO question as an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16634940/how-to-convert-a-sql-date-to-a-datetime)

Comment: It isn't but it should be possible to cast it to the `DateTime`, shouldn't it? (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exzwfa5y%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)