# How to format date in C# using SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql, date-format

I have a console project that retrieves some data from a database. It is using a connection string. When I run the project I get date as `1/1/2010 12:00:00 AM`, but I want to get only the date - like `1/1/2010`.

The code looks like this:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Employees";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlConnection);

SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 

// this is for header
string _fname = "First Name"; 
string _lname = "Last Name"; 
string _dob = "DOB"; 

Console.WriteLine("{0} | {1} | {2}", _fname.PadRight(10), _lname.PadRight(10), _dob.PadRight(10));

while (dr.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} | {1} | {2}",
                      dr["FirstName"].ToString().PadRight(10),
                      dr["LastName"].ToString().PadRight(10),
                      // Below is what I want to format.
                      dr["DOB"].ToString().PadRight(10)
}

dr.Close();
```

I tried:

```
dr["DOB"].ToString(MM-dd-yyyy).PadRight(10)

dr["DOB"].Date.ToString(MM-dd-yyyy).PadRight(10)
```

However none of them works.

When reading data using database, how do I format date?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16634940/how-to-convert-a-sql-date-to-a-datetime

Answer (score 2):

Please try with below code snippet.

Old code:-

```
dr["DOB"].ToString().PadRight(10)
```

New code:-

Option 1

```
dr.GetDateTime(columnIndex).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Option 2

```
Convert.ToDateTime(dr["DOB"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Comment: I'd just cast rather than using `Convert.ToDateTime` - that way if the OP *does* have a string representation, they'll find out quickly via an error, and can adjust their code appropriately. If it's a string representation, `Convert.ToDateTime` could give an unexpected result due to cultural ambiguities - e.g. if the database returns 11/07/2019 for today, but the OP runs the code on a UK machine, `Convert.ToDateTime` will return July 11th. (Calling `dr.GetDateTime` is probably the best approach, IMO.)

Comment: Option1 worked. I like it because it is simple and easy! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can also get it converted from SQL.
Update the query :

```
SELECT *, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DOB, 103) as FormattedDOB from Employees
```

and your c# :

```
dr["FormattedDOB"].ToString().PadRight(10);
```

Comment: While that *can* work, I'd strongly recommend doing all presentation logic in the application rather than in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try this:

```
String.Format("{0:MM-dd-yyyy}", <YourDate>)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [custom date and time formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) to achieve your desired Format. 
Your code could look like so:

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM Employees";
var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlConnection);
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
var _fname = "First Name";
var _lname = "Last Name"; 
var _dob = "DOB"; 
Console.WriteLine("{0} | {1} | {2}", _fname.PadRight(10),_lname.PadRight(10),_dob.PadRight(10));
while (dr.Read())
{
   dt = (DateTime)dt["DOB"];
   Console.WriteLine("{0} | {1} | {2}",
   dr["FirstName"].ToString().PadRight(10),
   dr["LastName"].ToString().PadRight(10),
   dt.ToString("MM/dd/yy").PadRight(10));
}
dr.Close();
```

Possibly the return value of `dr["DOB"]` is string and not a date. in this case you could convert it to date and then `.ToString("MM/dd/yy")` or you could simply find the index of " " and then split the string like so:

```
var str = (string)dr["DOB"]
Console.Write(str.Split(' ')[0]);
```

This will return: `1/1/2010`

Comment: The OP has already said they've tried that - that code won't compile, because `object` doesn't have a `ToString(string)` overload.

Comment: @JonSkeet Of cause not, we have to cast first. But depending on the version of C# this wont work either because `dr["DOB"]` is nullable and can only be cast to `object?`.

Comment: That code still won't compile. Include a genuine cast, and you can mention the `!` if you think the C# 8 part is important.

Comment: Although I question your claim that it's nullable anyway. I'd just written `DateTime dt = (DateTime) reader["dob"];` in a C# 8 app targeting .NET Core 3.0, and it's fine. Given that null values are represented by `DBNull.Value`, I don't know why it *would* be nullable.

Comment: (I'd generally strongly advise using the cast operator instead of `as`, if you're going to unconditionally dereference the value afterwards. An InvalidCastException is much more useful than a NullReferenceException.)

Comment: All thought I have to admit that I avoid using genuine casts, because they are in my experience slower then reference casts and we cant inline code.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about not inlining - but they absolutely shouldn't be slower. Even if there are some corner cases where they are, I favour maintainability over speed. See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2013/09/19/casting-vs-quot-as-quot-embracing-exceptions/ for more on this.

Answer (score -2):

You Need to parse string value to DateTime first. Try Something like this

```
string datestr ="1/1/2010 12:00:00 AM";
DateTime dateTime;
var ds = DateTime.TryParse(datestr,out dateTime);
string outstr = dateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: I sure hope OP isn't storing dates in their database as strings... perhaps you should ask them about that?

Comment: Why will it be a string? `SqlDataReader` returns boxed types.

Comment: @probinanand: The declared type of the indexer is `object`, and I'd expect the result to be a `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset`.

Comment: Sorry dr["DOB"] is object and need to cast into DateTime

Comment: I stored dates as date in database.